# MSDeploy copy files to deployment folder not working

Tags: deployment, msbuild, web-deployment

I am trying to copy from files from build server to deployment server using MSbuild but I am getting error while deployement.

> More Information: The provider 'contentPath=Default Web
>   Site\member\bin' could not be found.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_PROVIDER_NOT_FOUND.
>   Error count: 1.

```
msdeploy  -AllowUntrusted -verb:sync   -source:contentPath="e:\scripts\References" 
          -dest:contentPath="Default Web Site\\member\\bin",appPoolConfig=member,
          computerName=$computerName -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

Answer (score 0):

`-dest:contentPath="Default Web Site\\member\\bin"` should be the actual physical directory path of your web application. e.g.: "C:\wwwroot\MyApp\".